# Make function from method warning is coming while rapping method under class in python

Tags: python

I am creating one basic example of a class with different methods and having below error while doing it.

import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class SchoolTeacher:

```
def test_TeacherName(self):
    print("print the name of teacher")

def test_TeacherAddress(self):
    print("print the address of teacher")

def test_TeacherPhoneNumber(self):
    print("print phone number of teacher")
```

But it's giving me the below warning. I guess its a warning:
[Wrarning show in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1fGj.png)

Also, I am not seeing anything running on the console out and its saying empty suite
[Link to show empty suite warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahvkv.png)

**Conftest file**

```
import pytest
  @pytest.fixture()
  def setup():
    print("i will be executed first")
    yield
    print("please print me at the last")
```

Attaching folder strutcure:[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AQeG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use `pytest.mark.usefixtures`

`sandbox.py` and `conftest.py` in the same folder.

`conftest.py` code:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    print("i will be executed first")
    yield
    print("please print me at the last")
```

`sandbox.py` code:

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('setup')
class Test_SchoolTeacher:

    def test_TeacherName(self):
        print("print the name of teacher")

    def test_TeacherAddress(self):
        print("print the address of teacher")

    def test_TeacherPhoneNumber(self):
        print("print phone number of teacher")
```

command pytest [your test file name] -s,such as `pytest sandbox.py -s`,result:

```
============================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.7, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\work_code\sandbox
plugins: forked-1.3.0, xdist-2.1.0
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                              

sandbox.py i will be executed first
print the name of teacher
.please print me at the last
i will be executed first
print the address of teacher
.please print me at the last
i will be executed first
print phone number of teacher
.please print me at the last


============================================================================= 3 passed in 0.02s ==============================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you for the above comment. But I am using fixture in conftest .py file.Sorry! I should have attached the file above.

Comment: Attached conftest fille above.

Comment: Attaching folder structure

Comment: @anant raj I'm using same folder structure, just change `sandbox.py` to your test file name,`test_python2.py`

Comment: I can see now what is the mistake.The classname should be like this "Test_SchoolTeacher" or "TestSchoolTeacher".This is the reason why it is not picking and saying the suite is empty .Can you tell me the root cause why it is so?

Comment: @anant raj https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/naming_conventions.html, Test method names or function names should start with “test_”, as in test_example. Methods with names that don’t match this pattern won’t be executed as tests.